# Ember Octane How to access Model data in Component

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading from Ember Classic to Ember Octane 3.17.0.

**Question:**

How do I access model data in a component?

**Context:**

I am attempting to allow for reset password functionality. This sends a URL string to the user's e-mail. When they click on the link, I am able to query the string and load the userId and token into the model. However, I cannot access that model data in the component. In Classic, I achieved this with the `didReceiveAttrs` method, which is now deprecated. The documentation suggests using getters, but I am not clear on how that is done.

See the code below.

**Note:** I have not placed this in Ember Twiddle because I do not know how; that is another learning curve; and I tried looking for a walk-through but could not find one. If anyone wants to load this into Ember Twiddle then they have the code necessary to do so.

**Template Component HBS:**

```
<div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
    <div>
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>
        <form class="m-t" role="form" {{on "submit" this.resetPassword}}>
            {{#each @errors as |error|}}
                <div class="error-alert">{{error.detail}}</div>
            {{/each}}
            <Input @type="hidden" @value={{@resetPasswordModel.userId}} />
            <Input @type="hidden" @value={{@resetPasswordModel.token}} />
            <div class="form-group">
                <Input @type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" @value={{this.newPassword}} required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <Input @type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" @value={{this.confirmPassword}} required="true" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Reset Password</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Template HBS:**

```
<Clients::ResetPasswordForm @resetPasswordModel={{this.model}} @resetPassword={{action 'resetPassword'}} @errors={{this.errors}} />
```

**Route:**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import AbcUnAuthenticatedRouteMixin from '../../mixins/abc-unauthenticated-route-mixin';

export default class ResetPasswordRoute extends Route.extend(AbcUnAuthenticatedRouteMixin) {

    model(params) {

        return {
            userId: params.strUserId,   // The strUserId found in the query parameters of the reset password URL.
            newPassword: '',
            confirmPassowrd: '',
            token: params.strToken,     // The strToken found in the query parameters of the reset password URL.
        };
    }
}
```

**Component JS:**

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ResetPasswordForm extends Component {

    @tracked userId;
    @tracked newPassword;
    @tracked confirmPassword;
    @tracked token;

    @action
    resetPassword(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        this.args.resetPassword({
            userId: this.userId,
            newPassword: this.newPassword,
            confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword,
            token: this.token
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller JS:**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ResetPassword extends Controller {

    @service ajax;

    queryParams = ['strUserId', 'strToken'];
    strUserId = null;
    strToken = null;

    @action
    resetPassword(attrs) {

    if(attrs.newPassword == undefined || attrs.newPassword == null || attrs.newPassword == '' ||
        attrs.confirmPassword == undefined || attrs.confirmPassword == null || attrs.confirmPassword == '' ||
        attrs.newPassword != attrs.confirmPassword) 
        {

            this.set('errors', [{
                detail: "The new password and confirm password must be the same and their values and cannot be blank.  Reset password was not successful.",
                status: 1005,
                title: 'Reset Password Failed'
            }]);

            this.set('model', attrs);
        }
        else {

            this.ajax.request(this.store.adapterFor('application').get('host') + "/clients/reset-password", {
                method: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 
                    data: {
                        attributes: {
                            "userid" : attrs.userId,
                            "new-password" : attrs.newPassword,
                            "confirm-password" : attrs.confirmPassword,
                            "token" : attrs.token
                        },
                        type: 'reset-passwords'
                    }
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
                    'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
                }
            })
            .then(() => {

                // Transistion to the reset-password-success route.
                this.transitionToRoute('clients.reset-password-success');
            })
            .catch((ex) => {

                this.set('errors', ex.payload.errors); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the model data in the component by initializing you attribute using this.args

```
@tracked userId = this.args.resetPasswordModel.userId;
```

and  in the component  template

```
<Input @type="hidden" @value={{this.userId}} />
```